# Focus changed on LoadMore Button click in Windows Phone Application Page

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my Windows Phone application I have a ListBox with Load More button, in one of my pages. At the bottom of the page a TextBox and a button is present. when I click on the Load More button  at the bottom of listbox, the focus automatically goes to the textbox and the keypad is shown. I don't need to go the focus to the textbox on buttonclick. How this problem occures and how can I overcome this problem.

The xaml of style used for the listbox shown below

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxMore" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">
                        <StackPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0.5">
                                <Button Content="Load More..." Name="btnLoadMore" Visibility="Visible" Background="White" Foreground="#FF176DDC" Click="btnLoadMore_Click"></Button>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

The xaml of the listbox shown below

```
<ListBox x:Name="userDetailsList" SelectionMode="Multiple" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxMore}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0.5,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Width="440">
                    <Grid Width="430">
                        <Image Source="{Binding UserImage}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I click on loadmore button the focus goes to the textbox that placed below the listbox. There is only one textbox is there.

Comment: Post some code. But try this once in your void loadmorebutton_click{  loadMoreButton.Focus();                                               }

Comment: You tap on a button and the focus goes to a random textbox? If you're using a textbox instead of a button for "load more", try using textblock instead.

Comment: The Load More button is added in listbox style. It is a button not a textbox or a textblock.

Comment: It's unclear to me how the button puts focus on a random textbox unless you're using a call to Focus method of that particular textbox.

Comment: Without showing us some markup and code, no one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: provide the code for btnLoadMore_Click. I guess you are setting textbox.focus somewhere in your code which is getting triggered due to some tap event. I f you cant provide the code please debug it using breakpoints.